# Any ideas of how I can make my previous and next buttons on either side of image?

Tags: javascript, html, image, button

How can I make my previous and next buttons on either side of image? This is my code:

```html
<head>
  <title>change picture</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function displayNextImage() {
      x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
      document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
    }

    function displayPreviousImage() {
      x = (x <= 0) ? images.length - 1 : x - 1;
      document.getElementById("img").src = images[x];
    }

    function startTimer() {
      setInterval(displayNextImage, 5000);
    }

    var images = [],
      x = -1;


<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
 var imlocation = "images/";
 var currentdate = 0;
 var image_number = 0;
 function ImageArray (n) {
   this.length = n;
   for (var i =1; i <= n; i++) {
     this[i] = ' '
   }
 }
 image = new ImageArray(3)



      
    images[0] = "";
    images[1] = "";
    images[2] = "";
    images[3] = "";
    
 var rand = 60/image.length
 function randomimage() {
    currentdate = new Date()
    image_number = currentdate.getSeconds()
    image_number = Math.floor(image_number/rand)
    return(image[image_number])
 }
 document.write("<img src='" + imlocation + randomimage()+ "'>");
//-->
</script>
  
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="startTimer()">
  <center><div id="img-box">
    <img id="img" src="" />
    </div></center>
    
    
    <button class="button button400" onclick="displayPreviousImage()">Previous</button>

              
       <button class="button button400"onclick="displayNextImage()">Next</button>
</body>
```

Comment: removed fluff, but the question still deserves to be closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-order some of the elements like this:

```
<body onload="startTimer()">
         <button class="box button button400" onclick="displayPreviousImage()">Previous</button>

         <div class="box" id="img-box">
           <img width="200" height="100" id="img" src="" />
         </div>

         <button class="box button button400" onclick="displayNextImage()">Next</button>
    </body>
```

And add CSS script:

```
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

JSFiddle : [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/qb4y0hoo/)